# Amplify 29 kHz signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, signal, frequency

I generated a 29 kHz sine wave using an STM32 DAC periphal. The sine wave has 2.96 V output, but I need to make it at least 10-12 V. I tried using TL084, OP07CP, AD620 but the TL084 and OP07 don't amplify it. The AD620 makes the output voltage around 4.5V but it becomes square wave (gain was supposed to be 4). Supply voltages are +15V and -15V.

I also tried some transistor circuit designs but the transistor makes my signal square.

How can I amplify my 29 kHz signal?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9PsUo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Tell us more about what you tried, with schematics. I expect you're not hooking the parts up right, because any of those op amps should have worked fine.

Comment: I am 99% sure this can be done with most of those opamps. You have to show what **schematic** you used. 29 kHz is **NOT** high frequency. I've designed 29 GHz amplifiers so.. Also, if you think that the model of opamp makes that much difference then you have a lot to learn about using opamps. Without a **schematic** any further discussion is meaningless.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  I'm new here so i dont know how to add picture of schematic. I tried to do non inverting one. I used 2 resistors. R1 from (-) of opamp to output. R2 from (-) of opamp to ground. I got a input of opamp from stm32 PA4 pin. So there is not a schematic of signal generator. Also im junior electronics engineer. I dont know how to deal with this issue.

Comment: @OğuzhanYılmaz When you're editing the question, there's a button near the top that looks like a little circuit, with a diode, a capacitor, and a resistor. Click that to draw your circuit.

Comment: *I'm new here so i dont know how to add picture of schematic.* How about 1) trying some of the buttons 2) reading the help. *im junior electronics engineer.* Congratulations, if you want to lose the "junior" part then get used to "figuring out how things work" by yourself. It's not hard, it's an attitude thing, it is "I have not learned this so I cannot do this" versus "I can figure this out myself". What do you prefer?

Comment: +1 for having the ground symbols pointing down towards the ground. Please [edit] your question again to say what voltage you are using to drive the op-amp.

Comment: I suggest that you search in Google for "opamp amplifier circuit" and then press the "Images" tab to see lots of schematics to see how it is drawn by most people. Then draw it in the same way (ground pointing down etc.).

Comment: And tell us what the power supply rails are. Just in case you're trying to get 12V out of a 5V supply.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Supply voltages are +15V and -15V

Comment: What load is this circuit driving?

Comment: You say you have a 2.96 volt sine wave output that you want to amplify to 10-12 volts. If you are talking RMS volts, then 10 volts is over 28 V :P-P. Common op-amps cannot provide that level of output. That is probably why you see clipping at the output of your circuits.

Comment: @ThePhoton Piezoceramic ring.

Comment: What are the supplies? that opamp is not single supply

Comment: @Kırambor:  This is not a forum where you add "solved" to the title.  If someone's answer solved your problem, you click "Accept" on that answer.  That marks the question as properly answered and solved as well as giving the answering person a few points for helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. If you are expecting a sine wave that is centered about approximately 0V either couple it capacitively (eg. 100nF from the MCU and 10K from the op-amp non-inverting input to ground) or add a resistor as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTbfFm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

But it still should work as drawn, the sine wave will just be offset  by +4.3 * 1.5V = 6.45V and will be just short of saturating near the positive rail.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've added the schematic, it's clear that R2 is in the wrong location. Here's a comparison between what you drew, and what you probably meant.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG97d7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yeah it was the right one, sorry. Could it be because i got signal from microcontroller ? Because its not %100 pure sine wave.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: *Because its not %100 pure sine wave.* Sinewaves with absolutely no distortion **do not exist** in the real world, these only exist on paper. There's always some distortion and / or noise.